# Python can I get screenshot of website faster?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

at the moment I want to automate a web game. In order to do this I need to get pixels from the screen, I did this like this:

```
data = driver.get_screenshot_as_file("screen.png") #Take Screenshot
image = Image.open("screen.png")
numpy_array = np.asarray(image, dtype=np.uint8) #Get Numpy-Array
```

but that is a bit to slow for my use so I want to know if there is a better/faster way of getting a picture of the screen/website.

PS: I had the idea, that python could "look" at my screen and gets a "live" preview. But I don't know if how I could do that and I dont know if this would be much faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the PyAutoGUI module that has [screenshot](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/screenshot.html) functions.

It can be pretty fast and can be executed on separate thread. But I would suggest not to use it.

Because `driver.get_screenshot_as_file` captures the browser window even if it is in the background, even in headless mode. Other ways of screenshotting capture only the window that is visible on screen and won't work in headless mode.